# Is there any way that I can reset the sensor after I have killed the chased body so that the sensor can pick up bodies in range?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

I have it so when a sensor collision is detected the body the sensor is attached to will home in on the other body detected, while it does this the sensor ignores other bodies it detects. The problem is that when the body with the sensor kills the other body and hence stops seeing it, any other bodies in the sensor range are not being detected as they were previously ignored when the body was still being chased, aka ONLY SENSED ONCE.

Is there any way that I can reset the sensor after I have killed the chased body so that the sensor can pick up bodies in range?

Comment: provide you code please !!

Comment: I think we would require some code please. Also your problem is need to be a little more explained. What do u mean by killed?

Comment: You can keep a list of everything that the body with sensor attached is touching, and update that list as necessary when you get BeginContact and EndContact callbacks for the sensor.

Comment: Yeah I've done that but I did it with dst, I never though of end contact for that though, atm I iterate through list checking distances. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered:
You can keep a list of everything that the body with sensor attached is touching, and update that list as necessary when you get BeginContact and EndContact callbacks for the sensor.